# SQL How to: from two tables that has 2 same data in other named columns, one of them need to be counted

Tags: mysql, sql, database

*Hello there. I am not good in combining and indexing data from two or more tables in SQL databases and I want to learn it.
I am in need of help, I have modeling situation like this:
I have two tables:*

STUDENTS:

```
ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME,DATE_OF_BIRTH, CLASS,
1, Petr, Fish, 4.3.1984, 4A
2, John, Stone, 5.5.1990, 4A
3, Jack, Clark, 6.3.1983, 4A
4, George, Field, 5.8.1955, 4A
5, John, Rock, 6.1.1999, 4B
6, Patrick, Light, 1.11.1983, 4B
```

*and*

POINTS_MATH:

```
STUDENT_ID, POINTS
1, 15
1, 20
2, 30
3, 11
3, 5
4, 3
```

*ID in first table and STUDENTS_ID in second represent same values, for result rows with same STUDENTS_ID must be counted and assigned to right ID 
and I need result table:*

ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME,DATE_OF_BIRTH, CLASS, (sum of POINTS by STUDENTS_ID)

*in case a) it may seen:*

```
ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME,DATE_OF_BIRTH, CLASS, (sum of points by ID(STUDENTS_ID))
1, Petr, Fish, 4.3.1984, 4A, 35
2, John, Stone, 5.5.1990, 4A, 30
3, Jack, Clark, 6.3.1983, 4A, 16
4, George, Field, 5.8.1955, 4A, 3
```

*in case b) also with "no points" result, it may seen:*

```
ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME,DATE_OF_BIRTH, CLASS, (sum of points by ID(STUDENTS_ID))
1, Petr, Fish, 4.3.1984, 4A, 35
2, John, Stone, 5.5.1990, 4A, 30
3, Jack, Clark, 6.3.1983, 4A, 16
4, George, Field, 5.8.1955, 4A, 3
5, John, Rock, 6.1.1999, 4B, unknown
6, Patrick, Light, 1.11.1983, 4B, unknown
```

*And one more question: how and which kind of index can I use for more efective query in case of plenty datas?
Thanks very much for every answer.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **left join** use the below index which will be helpful in fetching the results faster

```
 create index index1 on POINTS_MATH(STUDENT_ID)
```

Use the below Query to get Results As You've wanted

```
select 
t.ID as ID,
t.FIRST_NAME as FIRST_NAME,
t.LAST_NAME as , 
t.DATE_OF_BIRTH as DATE_OF_BIRTH, 
t.CLASS as CLASS, 
case when t.SUM is null then 'unknown' else t.SUM end as SUM_OF_POINTS 
FROM
(SELECT ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, DATE_OF_BIRTH, CLASS, SUM(POINTS) as SUM
FROM STUDENTS S LEFT JOIN POINTS_MATH P
ON S.ID = P.STUDENT_ID
GROUP BY ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, DATE_OF_BIRTH, CLASS) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
SELECT ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, DATE_OF_BIRTH, CLASS SUM(POINTS)
FROM STUDENTS S INNER JOIN POINTS_MATH P
ON S.ID = P.STUDENT_ID
GROUP BY ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, DATE_OF_BIRTH, CLASS
```

Hope this helps.